# How do I add a "Send email" button to each row of a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 4 columns of input for writing an email

[image]

I want to (quickly) create a button for each row (all added in, say, column D) that will send an email utilizing the info *only* from the row that the button is situated in.

How do I do this?

- **How do I quickly add multiple identical looking buttons to each row but in such a way that each button only triggers sending an email using info from it's own row?**
- **How do I code such a script function so that it changes which row it grabs data from to only be the "current" row?**

---

What I've tried so far:

I've added a button to a single row using Insert > Drawing and assigned it the name of a custom function (`sendEmail`).

My Script:

```
    function sendEmail() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var email = e.values[0];
      var subject = e.values[1];
      var message = e.values[2];
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message)
    }
```

- Is `e.values` the best way to access specific columns?
- **How do I add code to narrow the script to working on only the row in which its assigned button is situated in?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an event trigger because clicking an image doesn't get any data from the sheet. The easier way would be to target the active cell in the row and select the correct range using Apps Script.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  // define a couple constants for the function
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Make sure the selected row has text
  if(sheet.getActiveCell().isBlank()) {
    ui.alert("Please select a row with a message");
    return;
  }

  // if valid, get the correct row of data.
    var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

  // get the range for that row
    var rowRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

  // Build the object to use in MailApp
    var address = rowRange[0][0];
    var subj = rowRange[0][1];
    var body = rowRange[0][2];

    var msg = "Address: " + address + "\nSubject: " + subj + "\nBody: " + body;

  // Here for illustration only
    ui.alert(msg, ui.ButtonSet.OK)

    // MailApp.sendEmail(address, subj, body);

    // set the send status in col 4
    sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue("Sent");
}
```

This way, you can have a single image in the sheet which runs a single function. Adding images for each row would get cumbersome. This is lightweight and effective.

You'd want to think about some other data validation steps before actually sending the message, but this should get you started.

Comment: so will this just send all the emails at once (i.e. will just your single function run for all rows each time)?

Comment: This sends an email for a single selected row, modeled on your question. You could rewrite the loop to send individual messages for multiple selected rows, though.

Comment: Finally got to test this. Works like a charm! Thanks very much for the elegant and simple solution.

Comment: Could I ask a follow-up request? (maybe as an update to your answer if you're willing). How could I add a bit at the end of the code to make a 5th column include "Email Sent" after the email was successfully sent for that row?

Comment: Added one line at the end to set the status in col 4. You can also use the value in this cell to protect against accidental sending. As is, it'll send another email.

Comment: Thanks! If I end up not selecting the "OK" button in the UI popup (which I really like, btw), which causes the email not to send, will the status still be assigned to "Sent"? If so, how can we make that conditional? (i.e., how can we make the status assignment using `setValue` conditional on a UI button click)?

Comment: No, the `return` halts execution in JavaScript/Google apps script. The code is executed top to bottom so a return prevents anything else from happening.

Comment: Got it! Many thanks for being so patient with me and walking me through all these points! Your helpfulness is very refreshing here at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get what you asked for. A send email button on every row with the accompanying data from that row.

Code.gs

```
function getEmails() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var br='<br />';
  var s='<table border="1">';
  s+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>', vA[0][0],vA[0][1],vA[0][2]);
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr><td>' + vA[i][0] + '</td><td>' + vA[i][1] + '</td><td>' + vA[i][2] + '</td><td>';
    s0=Utilities.formatString('\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\'',  vA[i][0], vA[i][1], vA[i][2])
    s+='<input type="button" value="Email Row ' + Number(i + 1) + '" onClick="sendMyEmail(' + s0 + ');" /></td></tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  return s; 
}

function showMy1Dialog()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myemail');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Title')
}

function sendEmail(email,subj,body)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(email + ', ' + subj + ', ' + body);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subj,body);
  Logger.log('\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\'',email,subj,body);
}
```

myemail.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayEmails).getEmails();
      });//gets data from spreadsheet on document ready
    function displayEmails(hl)
    {
      document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=hl;
    }
    function sendMyEmail(email,subj,body)
    {
      google.script.run.sendEmail(email,subj,body);
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="mydiv">

   </div>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what some of this is doing?

Comment: Do you have any specific questions?