# Create a "send email" button for selected row of data - GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

[Google-Sheets Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJwhp.png)

I have set up a Google-Sheets including columns/rows of employees work for the week (how many calls answered, emails sent per day), image attached. At the end of the week, I want to send an email to each employee with their data for the week.

Ideally, I would like to click a button and the email is sent to that specific employee. Each week the Google-Sheets will get longer and a new week of data will be inputted. I will then need to send the email again.

Comment: Have you attempted to record a macro in google sheets for this?

Comment: This may start you off, will need to be edited to meet your needs : https://stackoverflow.com/q/45890894/4961700

Comment: You've got two Excel tags on your question. What's Excel got to do with this?